# Azure Function App fails to authenticate with storage account, unless restarted

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account, shared-access-signatures

I am using a Durable Functions Orchestration to perform 3 tasks (activities). One of the tasks copies blobs from one storage account to another. I instantiate my source and target BlobServiceClient objects in the following way:

```
TokenCredential creds = new DefaultAzureCredential();
_sourceServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{_sourceStorageAcctName}.blob.core.windows.net"), creds);
_targetServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(_targetStorageAcctConnStr);

// default user delegation key expiration to 1 hour
_userDelegationKey = _sourceServiceClient.GetUserDelegationKey(null, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1));
```

The job should never take more than 10 minutes to complete given the amount of blobs to copy, hence why I set an expiration date of 1 hour for the User Delegation Key. Once I have the list of blobs to copy, I loop through it and generate a SAS with Read permissions and expiration of 5 minutes, and then call:

`targetBlobClient.StartCopyFromUri(sourceBlobSASURI)`

This is repeated for every blob in the list. My Azure account and the Function's managed identity have been added to the "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role in the **source storage account**. Testing locally in Visual Studio works fine. When I deploy the function to Azure and run it manually it works fine.

I then schedule the function to run on a daily basis, but now the function fails to authenticate to the storage account with the message below:

```
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:cf03b2fa-001e-0028-7aec-6e22a1000000
Time:2024-03-05T11:00:17.9880230Z
Status: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
ErrorCode: CannotVerifyCopySource

Content:
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><Error><Code>CannotVerifyCopySource</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:cf03b2fa-001e-0028-7aec-6e22a1000000
Time:2024-03-05T11:00:17.9880230Z</Message></Error>

Headers:
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: cf03b2fa-001e-0028-7aec-6e22a1000000
x-ms-client-request-id: d6e94e13-cb3e-44e8-a874-df40a9a9faa6
x-ms-version: 2023-08-03
x-ms-error-code: CannotVerifyCopySource
Date: Tue, 05 Mar 2024 11:00:17 GMT
Content-Length: 322
Content-Type: application/xml
\r
\r
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.StartCopyFromURL(String copySource, Nullable`1 timeout, IDictionary`2 metadata, Nullable`1 tier, Nullable`1 rehydratePriority, Nullable`1 sourceIfModifiedSince, Nullable`1 sourceIfUnmodifiedSince, String sourceIfMatch, String sourceIfNoneMatch, String sourceIfTags, Nullable`1 ifModifiedSince, Nullable`1 ifUnmodifiedSince, String ifMatch, String ifNoneMatch, String ifTags, String leaseId, String blobTagsString, Nullable`1 sealBlob, Nullable`1 immutabilityPolicyExpiry, Nullable`1 immutabilityPolicyMode, Nullable`1 legalHold, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.StartCopyFromUriInternal(Uri source, IDictionary`2 metadata, IDictionary`2 tags, Nullable`1 accessTier, BlobRequestConditions sourceConditions, BlobRequestConditions destinationConditions, Nullable`1 rehydratePriority, Nullable`1 sealBlob, BlobImmutabilityPolicy destinationImmutabilityPolicy, Nullable`1 legalHold, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.StartCopyFromUri(Uri source, IDictionary`2 metadata, Nullable`1 accessTier, BlobRequestConditions sourceConditions, BlobRequestConditions destinationConditions, Nullable`1 rehydratePriority, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
...
```

Even when running it manually after seeing the failure, it fails with the same message. However, if I restart the Function App and then run it once more, it works fine. I am struggling to figure out how come just restarting the Function App fixes the issue? It's not a permament fix however, as eventually the scheduled execution will hit the error again, typically within 24 hours.

I am using the "in-process" model and wonder if this has anything to do with it. Any insights into this behavior is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue here. The class containing my functions was declared as static, including the property that instantiated my **_sourceServiceClient** and **_targetServiceClient** objects. Hence, everything works fine on the first execution, but on subsequent executions, it reuses the static objects with the values assigned during the first execution. So after 1 hour, the user delegation key expires causing the error I posted.

By removing the static property of the class and its properties, a new user delegation key will be generated with every execution, solving the problem.

This also explains why re-starting the function app causes everything to work again, as the class is instantiated newly after 1st execution.